# Kinetic Kame vs. Lunar Loggerhead distribution

Tags: ros, ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
I am a newbie in the ROS World and I started few days ago reading materials and documentation about this fantastic framework. I covered the *Get an overwiew* (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Introduction) and I am now in the process of starting from the beginner level tutorials.
This implies that I configure ROS environment but, in order to do this, I have to choose first the ROS distro I want to work on. Having a look at the distributions that are available for ROS I can see that both the **Kinetic Kame** and **Lunar Loggerhead** are available. I feel more confident in selecting the Kinetic Kame (as it seems like it has a longer support), but it has been released a year (more or less) before the Lunar Loggerhear, that is not a small amount of time.

Could someone guide me through this decision point providing the proper rationale?

Thanks indeed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286247/kinetic-kame-vs.-lunar-loggerhead-distribution/) by [Starscream](https://answers.ros.org/users/34271/starscream/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-22**:\

> Having a look at the LTS distro [..] I can see [..] Lunar Loggerhead

Just a comment: Lunar is not an LTS.

**Comment by [Starscream](https://answers.ros.org/users/34271/starscream/) on 2018-03-22**:
Thanks for let me notice this, I edited my post as it was a wrong information and voted up for your support.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why not start with the Kinetic Kame distribution and switch when you need to? Or if you just start learning ROS, you can use either one for now, and switch to Ubuntu 18.04 and ROS Melodic Morenia (both LTS) in May. That will give you a stable and up-to-date platform once you're up and running.

---

Originally posted by [Maarten](https://answers.ros.org/users/34054/maarten/) with karma: 206 on 2018-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Starscream](https://answers.ros.org/users/34271/starscream/) on 2018-03-23**:
That's great! Thanks a lot for your hint!!